# Random white-space after content (Webkit browser bug)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, column-count

I have been getting an unknown white-space at the bottom of my Service pages. I'm using `column-count: 2;` to break the images up between two columns.

**Update: This is a Webkit browser problem**

**The problem** is the extra space at the bottom of `mainCont`, left side column.

If the images all line up flush then there is about a 30px of unneeded white-space. Although if the images do not line up flush then there is about a 50-70px of extra white-space. I have a 10px padding on the main containers but I can't find what is creating the extra spacing.

Here is a [JSFIDDLE (remove/show in url to view code)](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/XxP6N/show/) to see what the problem is. Also here is the [Live Site](http://chatfielddrilling.com/Chatfield%20V2/index.php) so you can see how it affects each one of the service pages.

CSS for main container:

```
.mainCont {
    width: 100%;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 2.5%;
}
```

**Edit**

There is about `160px` of extra space at the bottom minus 20px(mainCont and gridbox img equals 20px in padding).

[image: Extra space and image's padding]

Comment: I am not able to see 160px gap at the bottom.

Comment: @Learning What browser are you viewing it on then?

Comment: Yeah I just checked it in firefox and IE which, display it correct. This is a webkit browser problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have been making research since ysterday.

1. If image sizes are equal, no problem on all browsers
2. If image sizes are different, extra space occurs at the bottom of
   the page.

This is the bug of chrome browser. There is something wrong with balancing algorithm. They haven't resolved this issue yet. You can see [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=297782)

Comment: That is for between the images and 10px is not 50-70px. Let me open a screenshot in PS and I'll know the exact amount of space that should not be there.

Comment: Refer to the image I added.

Comment: By the way this issue is not valid for FF

Comment: or IE so it is a webkit problem

Comment: If image sizes are different, extra spaces occurs at the bottom of page. This is a chrome bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=297782

Comment: If you update your answer since it is a known bug I will mark it as the correct one.

Comment: Thank you for all of the help you provided!

Comment: adding `--enable-region-based-columns` as stated in comment https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=297782#c6 removes the space. May be they will implement soon.