# White space after footer on Wordpress theme in Chrome and IE

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-chrome, genesis

I purchased a WordPress Genesis theme and there seems to be white space after the the footer. I'm developing on localhost, so here's the demo site:

http://demo.cdils.com/utility-pro/

I've tried the following:

1. Chrome has a user agent style sheet. I've tried marking the body
   and/or html with a padding of 0 and margin of 0.
2. Add a massively large height to the footer - the white space disappears, but obviously looks hideous.

If someone is able to figure a way to correct this in chrome with the inspect element, I would absolutely love your thoughts.

Comment: I should add. This works perfectly in firefox.

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21099541/random-white-space-after-content-webkit-browser-bug

Comment: Interesting Manoj. I'm just not sure how to fix that. There are different image sizes, but I don't know if that's the problem. I'll try to think of something creative. If anyone else has ideas, I'd appreciate it.